# WPF Gridsplitter does not work with UseLayoutRounding

Tags: wpf

If the wpf application has set UseLayoutRounding to true for the window then a gridsplitter will no longer work for some window widths (it will be stuck at its original position), such as the example below.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="401"
        UseLayoutRounding="True">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
            long string that does not fit within the textblock - long string that does not fit within the textblock
        </TextBlock>

        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="50" Background="LightBlue" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2">
            long string that does not fit within the textblock - long string that does not fit within the textblock
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Notice that for the example to generate the error the window Width must be 401, the text in the textboxes must be longer than the textbox and UseLayoutRounding must be true.

Anyone that knows how to avoid this or have any workaround? I don't want to set UseLayoutRounding to false since it causes rendering artifacts in my application.

**Edit:**
For others with the same problem, I found this user made component that solves the problem: http://blog.onedevjob.com/2011/12/11/fixing-wpf-gridsplitter/ Would still be nice if it could be solved with the default wpf components though.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. One obvious workaround is to set TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" for at least one of TextBlock elements but I'm sure this was not your intention.

Another workaround is to not to give a splitter it's own grid column and instead place it in the second, last column. Seems to do the trick:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0">
        long string that does not fit within the textblock - long string that does not fit within the textblock
    </TextBlock>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Margin="-25,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="50" Background="LightBlue" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="25,0,0,0">
        long string that does not fit within the textblock - long string that does not fit within the textblock
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it doesn't really work though, it just changes for what window width the splitter gets stuck. A window width of 403 for the code above will still generate the error.